# iPhone ios6 scrolls to top unless bottom of page is visible (ajax table)

Tags: iphone, ajax, ipad, codeigniter

On my webpage, I use ajax to load some offers.  Issue shows up on ios6... unless the bottom of the page is visible, as soon as I scroll down into the available offers, the browser jumps to the top of the page.  This happens the same in both chrome and mobile safari in ios6.  If i very quickly scroll to "bounce" the bottom of the page, it stays.  As soon as i scroll up and bottom is no longer visible, it jumps to the top.

Anyone have any idea how to code around this, so that the scrolling works properly?